# How can I trust an mobile app's identity that is calling my web service?

Tags: web-services, security, mobile-application

A solution I'm building will involve a genericised back-end web service and a number of different mobile apps (for different clients). Each app should receive some different configuration information, so at some point the app will need to call in to the web service and identify what kind of app it is.

For example if I embed a token of sorts, an attacker could decompile and grab this token, and then call in to the API on behalf of a different app. How can I make sure that this identity cannot be stolen? I need a way to confidently identify that an app is who it says it is.

It might be worth noting that some business requirements dictate that some apps do not need user registration, so the ability to secure this via user logins isn't an option in all cases.

Comment: You authenticate the client and then authorize access to the service. Different clients will be authorized for different levels of service. Here, the "client" can be the user or the machine or both since both can be security principals. The strongest/safest is client-side certificates; the lamest/weakest is passwords, which the web embraces. Prior to authenticating the client, you have to provision them. Provisioning might consist of the client enrollment or the client providing a public key or certificate or password.

Comment: Also see [authentication and authorization](https://www.google.com/search?q=authentication+and+authorization) and [provisioning](https://www.google.com/search?q=user+and+device+provisioning)

Comment: The clients will be apps in app stores, so any data would need to be present at the point of building a prod build of the same. Say a certificate was embedded, as noted in the OP what is to stop a malicious user extracting that certificate? Or is there simply only so much that can be done, and there will always be an implicit level of trust?

Comment: Provision them after your app installs, during the first launch.

Comment: But how can one app be discerned from another? They need different config depending on what product they are. The app will surely need to say, in one way or another, 'I am app A' or 'I am app B'?